# Как получить список команд работы с файлами в powershell?

Tags: windows-10, powershell

Как получить список команд работы с файлами в powershell?

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "список комманд работы с файлами"? Команды, которые могут что-то делать с файлами? Что конкретно? Опишите подробнее, что вы хотите получить на выходе. Можно почитать, например, здесь: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/cookbooks/working-with-files-and-folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать командлет `Get-Command` с параметром `*Item*`
Получаем

```
Get-Command *Item*
```